# How to insert similarity operator for PostgreSQL fuzzy text search using trigram in Nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, trigram

I am trying to implement fuzzy text search with PostgreSQL on a Nodejs/Express server. I've got the query working using the "`ILIKE`" operator but it is very important that this query be optimised and I read that using the similarity operator "`%`" here would force use of the GIN index created on the title column using `gin_trgm_ops`. But for some reason, the query does not return any values using the "`%`" operator. I've tried escaping the string then concatenation which received some syntax errors. Any pointers would be appreciated.

This version is not working:

```
 var query = ['SELECT title, user FROM reviews']
 query.push("WHERE (title % $1) AND NOT (user = $2) AND ((approved_date IS NULL) OR (approved_date < now()))")
 query.push('ORDER BY similarity(title,$1) DESC LIMIT 99')
```

This version using `ILIKE` is working:

```
 var query = ['SELECT title, user FROM reviews']
 query.push("WHERE title ILIKE '%' || $1 || '%' AND NOT (user = $2) AND ((approved_date IS NULL) OR (approved_date < now()))")
 query.push('ORDER BY similarity(title,$1) DESC LIMIT 99')
```

Also, am I to understand from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE) that using the distance operator `<->` will not work properly here because I am using a GIN index rather than GIST? Thanks.

Comment: They do different things, so it is not surprising they give different results.  Both can use the index.  Use the one that will do the thing you want done.

Comment: If you want help with the syntax errors, show us what the error was, and what you did to cause it.

Comment: @jjanes What is the difference between the two? I was under the impression they were exactly the same. Pls provide more info, thanks.

Comment: @jjanes you legend!! I tried the query with similarity operator "%" again and its actually working ( I must have missed it after all the bad attempts). But the results are very shitty, it looks like its doing a whole word search and it is much slower than "ILIKE". What is the difference between using "%" and using "ILIKE"?